# How to insert data if conditions are correct

Tags: php, mysql, database, if-statement, insert

How can I insert data into mysql from a FORM if conditions are meet.

These are my codes.

`$sql0` check if similar data already exist

`$sql1` insert data to mysql

```
$wirebname   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["wirebname"]);
$wireaccname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["wireaccname"]);
$wireacno    = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["wireacno"]);
$wirebranchnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["wirebranchnumber"]);
$swift       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["swift"]);
$route       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["route"]);
$state       = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["state"]);
$country     = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["country"]);

$id = $_SESSION['loggedIn_cust_id'];
$sql0 = "
    SELECT wire_benef_id 
    FROM wire_beneficiary".$id." 
    WHERE wirebname='".$wirebname."'
        AND wireaccname='".$wireaccname."'
        AND wireacno='".$wireacno."'
        AND swift='".$swift."'
        AND route='".$route."'
";

$result = $conn->query($sql0);

$success = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $wire_account_number = $row["wireacno"];

    if ($wireacno != $wire_account_number) {
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO wire_beneficiary".$id." 
            VALUES(
                NULL,
                '$wirebname',
                '$wireaccname',
                '$wireacno',
                '$wirebranchnumber',
                '$swift',
                '$route',
                '$state'
                '$country',
                )
        ";

        if (($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE)) {
            $success = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $success = -1;
    }
}
```

If account number already exist, I want an error to be print out

If not it should be written into the database.

```
<?php
if ($success == 1) { ?>
    <p id="info"><?php echo "Beneficiary successfully added !\n"; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your code is open to sql injections. Try use pdo or prepared statements

Comment: i will, but can you please tell me how to insert the datas??

Comment: Why are you using double check when you are retreiving your desired row by `select` query

Comment: `if ($wireacno != $wire_account_number) {` will always false

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now try it

Answer (score 0):

You are using useless double checks. `if ($wireacno != $wire_account_number) {` returns always false as you are retrieving your desired row by `select` query. if it `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` returns true then obviously your account existed and you don't need another check. so try this code

```
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO wire_beneficiary".$id." VALUES(
                NULL,
                '$wirebname',
                '$wireaccname',
                '$wireacno',
                '$wirebranchnumber',
                '$swift',
                '$route',
                '$state'
                '$country',
            )";

    if (($conn->query($sql1) === TRUE)) {
        $success = 1;
    }
}
else {
    $success = -1;
 }

}
```

As mentioned above your code is vulnerable and open to sql injections to try use PDO or Prepared statements

Comment: @comphonia sorry. Typo error. I missed that line clearly. Thanks for indicating

Answer (score 0):

You can make 'Account number' column in database as a primary key.
So when you try to insert the same account number, from db you will get an exception for primary key violation.

(The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a table.
Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values, and cannot contain NULL values.
A table can have only one primary key, which may consist of single or multiple fields. Refer about primary key from [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) )

You can use that error to set insertion is successful or not.

Comment: that means i would have to add it as an auto column and they can only be one auto coloum. so do id auto increment??

Comment: No. It is not an auto increment column. I have edited the answer by adding reference to get to know about primary key. Go through that. As primary u can add unique values. Then you cannot add entry with the same acc no.